# JAVA Using IOUtils.toString with HttpEntity.getContent() converting the InputStream to null

Tags: java, inputstream

I have strange senario 
i have HTTP response which i try to convert to string , the problem is that the first time it is working but in the second time the InputStream data is null
and i have data only in response1

```
InputStream  is = entity.getContent();  
String response1 = IOUtils.toString(is, "utf-8");  // Here every thing is fine 
String respons2 = IOUtils.toString(is, "utf-8");   // Here the response2 is empty 
and is (InputStream) holding no data
```

what is wrong here i need to be able to hold the data in the InputStream for future   use in the code

Comment: That's because the InputStream is a stream. You consume data from it. That data is then no longer in the stream. In any case, I don't see what you're trying to do. Why not just String response2 = response1?

Comment: this is only to show apoint that i didn't understand , how can i solve it that 
i can use the stream after i allready used it ?

Comment: By default, it's not repeatable, when you passed it to response1, everything regarding that stream(except memory address allocation)  is wiped away since you terminated it by explicitly assigning it to a string response1.

Answer (score 2):

Your need is not very clear however, when checking the javadoc [httpEntity.getContent](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html#getContent()) I see the following:

> Returns a content stream of the entity. Repeatable entities are
>   expected to create a new instance of InputStream for each invocation
>   of this method and therefore can be consumed multiple times. Entities
>   that are not repeatable are expected to return the same InputStream
>   instance and therefore may not be consumed more than once.

Did you check that the httpEntity is repeatable by calling

```
httpEntity.isRepeatable()
```

if true, you could do the following:

```
InputStream  is = entity.getContent();  
String response1 = IOUtils.toString(is, "utf-8");

// retrieve a new instance of inputStream
is = entity.getContent();
String response2 = IOUtils.toString(is, "utf-8");
```

Last but not least (since I do not know your exact need), the previous code will helps if the entity is capable of producing its data more than once but nevertheless you should evaluate the cost between:

- consuming the data once and keep it in string
- consuming the data several times

Answer (score 1):

No, streams are not meant to be read from more than once.

If you want to keep the CONTENTS of the stream around for re-use, you can do that. In your case just re-use the **response1** String.

Comment: Your statement is true, but not applicable here.  An InputStream is not a java.util.stream.Stream.

Answer (score 0):

Before reading you should check whether the stream supports resetting. You can check the result of `InputStream#markSupported()` that tell you whether or not you can use the pair of methods `mark()/reset()`.

If mark supported then you can do `mark()` when reading and then `reset()` to go back to begin.

Answer (score 0):

If the httpEntity is not repeatable, you can wrap the InputStream in a BufferedInputStream; that way, you can reset it to allow re-reading. Essentially, the BufferedInputStream reads the data into an internal buffer the first time around, and then re-uses the buffer when you re-read.

```
final int bufferSize = 1_000_000; // about 1 MB; must be large enough to hold all the http content
InputStream  is = new BufferedInputStream(entity.getContent(), bufferSize);
is.mark(bufferSize);
String response1 = IOUtils.toString(is, "utf-8");
is.reset();
String respons2 = IOUtils.toString(is, "utf-8");
```